# DES Meet in the Middle

Tags: des

My professor showed us the basics of DES, and then displayed this slide where the Meet in the Middle attack can be used as a way of cracking DES. I believe at this stage we are doing 2DES, as opposed to DES or 3DES.

Could someone explain the math to me please?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. I'm not sure which textbook you use for your lecture, hope that you use more than the slides, These are well known well written in books like Menezes Handbook of Applied Cryptography chapter 7 section 7.2.3 multiple encryption and Lindell&Katz books'.

Comment: See this tag [tag:meet-in-the-middle-attack]

Comment: The _"Requires $2^{56} (K,X_k)$ pairs to be stored so not much worse than brute force on DES"_ part of this slide is seriously misleading. It's possible to reach that conclusion, but not with this argument.

Comment: brute force codebook attack on DES, surely. brute force key search has constant memory requirements

Comment: @kelalaka The problem is they all use different notation, compared to my professor, and I already have a below average knowledge of high school maths.

Comment: @kelalaka It is all beyond me, I struggle to understand it, sorry.

Comment: Also what is the difference, on the first line, between (m,c) and (m',c')? I assume they are just two different message, ciphertext pairs...